# Spring MVC: How to bind to nested object properties in the @ModelAttribute

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, powermock, spring-test-mvc

I have a unit test to carry out based on the following part of code:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/changePass", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView changePass(@ModelAttribute(TAPPLICATION) AppBean applicationBean, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, Principal principal, HttpServletRequest request) throws NSException, SQLException {
         // ...

         if (applicationBean != null
                    && applicationBean.getChangePassDto() != null
                    && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(applicationBean.getChangePassDto().getNewPassword())) {

                String newPassword = applicationBean.getChangePassDto().getNewPassword();
                // ...                   
            }
            // ...
```

The AppBean contains the following getter and setter:

```
private ChangePassDto changePassDto;   

   public ChangePassDto getChangePassDto() {
        return changePassDto;
    }

    public void setChangePassDto(ChangePasswordDto changePassDto) {
        this.changePassDto = changePassDto;
    }
```

Basically when I execute the unit test the method `applicationBean.getChangePassDto()` is `null` but `applicationBean` is not null. How can I initialise the `applicationBean.getChangePassDto()` so that it does not return `null`? I have initialised the other non object parameters with the `.param` method as it can be seen in my unit test.

I am also using Powermock as unit test framework.

Please find below part of my unit test:

```
    @Before
    public void setup() {

        request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        request.setAttribute(DispatcherServlet.OUTPUT_FLASH_MAP_ATTRIBUTE, new FlashMap());
        response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        session = new MockHttpSession();
        request.setSession(session);
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(request));

        //Added viewResolver to prevent circular view path error
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(appController).setViewResolvers(viewResolver).build();    
    }

    @Test
    public void changePass_ExpectC() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(passwordVal).validate(any(User.class), anyListOf(Params.class), any(Object.class),any(Errors.class));


        mockMvc.perform(post("/changePass").param("userLogName", "JOHN").param("userLogged", "userLogged").param("password", "password123").param("newPassword", "newPassword123").param("confirmNewPassword", "newPassword123"))
                 .andExpect(view().name(Constants.DENIED))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()
                 );
    }
```

Any idea how I can intitialise `applicationBean.getchangePassDto()` so that it is not null?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a new instance of `ChangePassDto` in your `AppBean`:

```java
public class AppBean {

  private ChangePassDto changePassDto = new ChangePassDto();

  public ChangePassDto getChangePassDto() {
    return changePassDto;
  }

  public void setChangePassDto(ChangePasswordDto changePassDto) {
    this.changePassDto = changePassDto;
  }

  // ...
}
```

You then need to use the full path to the properties in the nested DTO like this:

```java
mockMvc.perform(post("/changePass")
    .param("changePassDto.userLogName", "JOHN")
    .param("changePassDto.userLogged", "userLogged")
    .param("changePassDto.password", "password123")
    .param("changePassDto.newPassword", "newPassword123")
    .param("changePassDto.confirmNewPassword", "newPassword123"))
.andExpect(view().name(Constants.DENIED))
.andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: Hi, I have a question please if I add the new ChangePassDto() part in my appBean, spring will not manage the ChangePassDto  instance as it is not loaded by Spring?

Comment: In this scenario, Spring does not need to _manage_ your DTO. Rather, it just needs to bind the request parameters to the properties of your DTO. I'll update my answer accordingly.